# What will be the next term in this mathematical sequence?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

What will be next in this series?
$$0, 6, 24, 60, 120, 210, ...$$
I've tried it and noticed that the numbers are multiples of six. But I couldn't make a relation between them.

Comment: the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C6%2C24%2C60%2C120%2C210&language=english&go=Search) has three potential answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like

> sum of digit series
> f(n)=n*sumOfDigits(n-1)*sumOfDigits(n+1)

example:-

> f(1)=1*sumOfDigits(1-1)*sumOfDigits(1+1) = 1*0*2 = 0
> f(2)=2*sumOfDigits(2-1)*sumOfDigits(2+1) = 2*1*3 = 6
> f(3)=3*sumOfDigits(3-1)*sumOfDigits(3+1) = 3*2*4 = 24
> f(4)=4*sumOfDigits(4-1)*sumOfDigits(4+1) = 4*3*5 = 60
> f(5)=5*sumOfDigits(5-1)*sumOfDigits(5+1) = 5*4*6 = 120
> f(6)=6*sumOfDigits(6-1)*sumOfDigits(6+1) = 6*5*7 = 210

Answer:-

> f(7)=7*sumOfDigits(7-1)*sumOfDigits(7+1) = 7*6*8 = 336

Comment: That's copying my solution

Comment: In my series the answer will change after 10th term, so how it's same.
@TheSimpliFire

Answer (score 8):

It seems like a

> cube series.

Namely,

> cube of 1 is 1   then    1  - 1 = 0 
>  cube of 2 is 8   then    8  - 2 = 6 
>  cube of 3 is 27  then   27 -  3  = 24
>  cube of 4 is 64  then   64 -  4  = 60
>  cube of 5 is 125 then   125 - 5  = 120
>  cube of 6 is 216 then   216 - 6  = 210
>  cube of 7 is 343 then   343 - 7  = 336

Answer (score 4):

- Take differences between terms:

  > $6, 18, 36, 60, 90, ...$
- Notice that these are

  > $6$ times the triangular numbers $1, 3, 6, 12, 15, ...$

So the next difference should be

> $6\times 21 = 126$

and the next term should be

> $210+126=336$.

Comment: The multiplication on the third spoiler is incorrect. And also, the sequence can be found on the OEIS as a nice formula: https://oeis.org/A007531

Answer (score 4):

Simple Answer:

> The $n$th term is $n(n-1)(n+1)$ and thus the required one is the seventh term giving an answer of $$7(6)(8)=336.$$